# BASH - counting the number of executable files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Im trying to find the executables files and their total in a folder,its showing but the total is not this is my code below,can someone help me out were i am making mistakes,i am just a newbie trying to learn some bash scripting hope this is the right way of doing it thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
To="home/magie/d2"
cd "$To"
find . -type f -perm 755

if 
   find . -type f -perm 755
then
 echo | echo wc -l
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `if` structure and the `echo`'s

```
#!/bin/bash
To="home/magie/d2"
cd "$To"
find . -type f -perm 755

find . -type f -perm 755 | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find **all the executable** files then use this command:

```
find home/magie/d2 -type f -perm -u+rx | wc -l
```

OR

```
find home/magie/d2 -type f -perm +111 | wc -l
```

All the answers here are finding files with permission 755 only however keep in mind even 744 or 700 are also executable files by the user.

Comment: See also the `-executable` test.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: On my `Mac OS X 10.6.8` find doesn't have `-executable` option.

Comment: I should have mentioned that it's GNU-specific.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Yes that's right. I learned about that `-executable` option only few days ago. However since it wasn't available universally so I didn't use it in my answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1
files="$(find $dir -perm 755)"
total=$(wc -l <<< "$files")
echo "$files"
echo "Total: $total"
```

where the desired directory has to be passed as an argument in the command line and the quotes are used to preserve line breaks needed later by `wc` to correctly count the number of lines.

Comment: I wanted to say that we could use string heredoc : `total=$(wc -l <<<"$files")` but now not sure if thats any better. :)

Comment: @JaypalSingh I think here strings are not commonly used, but I find they are nice. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome :). I started learning bash 3-4 months ago and the first month I was just reading answers posted here on SO to get an idea of good practices. What I understood from reading the answers was that `pipes` are **bad** and so I formed a habit of using either heredoc syntax or command sub. I am still not completely sure of what exactly happens behind the scenes in each case. So looks like back2books. :)

Comment: @JaypalSingh: Pipes are not bad. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson From going through the answers posted on SO. The cons I gathered were it creates a new sub-shell, it forks a new process.

Comment: That's not "bad". Often, it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Use /111 to find any file that has any of the execute bits set.

find . -type f -perm /111 | wc -l

Answer (score 1):

From the command line a simple one-liner should do the trick -

```
wc -l < <(find /home/magie/d2 -type f -perm 755)
```

**`<(..)`** is [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Comment: Why not a simple pipe? `find . -type f -perm 755 | wc -l`

Comment: Won't that mean 3 processes (1xfind, 1xpipe, 1xwc) instead of 2 using command sub?

Comment: Command substitution creates a named pipe. Try `grep -l . <(echo foo)`

Comment: Hmm .. Thanks @DennisWilliamson. So there is no any benefit of using command sub over over pipe (I mean for this case). We would still be doing all of this in the same shell and not fork a new or is my understanding wrong? (Sorry I am still learning) and thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Actually, `<()` is called *process substitution*. Command substitution is `$()`. Pipes (in and of themselves) and process substitution do not create subshells, command substitution does. Pipes into, for example, `while` loops do create subshells (that's why you should use `done < <(foo)` instead of `foo | while`.

Comment: True my bad .. I had just posted an answer on command sub and that kinda got stuck in my head.